# SSL Error while using rpxnow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, rpxnow

I am using RPX for OpenID Authentication. I am getting the following error. It happens only in windows. It works perfectly in Mac. Can someone please guide me to solve this error.

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server c ertificate B: certificate verify failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE to the function where we check the openid rectifies the error.